# How to enable TLS for OC4J or OAS?

Tags: oracle, security, ssl, oc4j, oas

With the recent Poodle issue with SSLv3, we are trying to enable TLS on OC4J / OAS?

But we cannot find any concrete information to do so, we have tried adding the cypers, but this doesnt work.

Does anyone know how to enable TLS for OC4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally found the answer:

- Update to the latest version of OC4J 10.1.3.5 (we were running 10.1.3.3) - p8800528_101350_Generic
- Update the Oracle Interim Patching Tool opatch (p6880880_101000_SOLARIS64.zip)
- Apply the Critical Patch Update (CPU) April 2014 Critical Update Patch [cumulative] - (p18272678_101350_SOLARIS64.zip)
- Alter the ssl.conf files to enable TLS